# how to make my code into a function that inputs a file?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to coding and I would like to make the following script into a bash so that I could just input any file I want.

I want to make a folder and an output name base on the name of the input file. I would like to know how to do it?

Here's an example

in the terminal, I would like to run `bash script.sh alphanum.txt`

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

read file
mkdir "$file"
cut -d" " -f2- $file > new_"$file".txt
```

example of the input file named `alphanum.txt`:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

The output should be:

- a folder named `alphanum`
- a text file named new_alphanum.txt

wherein `new_alphanum.txt` will be:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this script, and it's unclear what your intention is. Please _edit your question_ to describe precisely what you want it to do.

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems in the code.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can do ***./test.sh alphanum.txt*** or with some specific path ***./test.sh ~/temp/alphanum.txt***

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(basename "$1")
foldername="${file%.*}"
mkdir -p "$foldername"
cut -d" " -f2- "$file" > new_"$file"
```

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies many missing quotes in the code.